# Ability to revert (update file to blob storage) and (db add/update via EF Core) after execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, concurrency, transactions, azure-blob-storage

My plan is to have 2 actions happening at the same time. Revert if 1 fails, but I have difficulty finding the approach for it.

- action 1, upload/ update file to blob storage (via namespace `Azure.Storage.Blobs` > `public class BlobContainerClient`)
- action 2,    add/ update record/ row on db (via EF Core)

The pseudocode is

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(<parameter-lists>)
{
  // authentication
  // verify file (name, size, ...)

  // PORTION THAT I HAVE DIFFICULTY
  // trying to do [database save] and [upload to storage blob] at the same time
  // if success, then good. return response
  // if [at least 1] fail, then REVERT both processes ([database save] and [upload to storage blob])
}
```

I am open to any suggestion.

- If they run one after the another, and we still have the ability to revert the first action, that's great too!

===========

Edit 1, a friend has this suggestion.

- this seems like a nice idea, but I am curious

  - if this method work
  - if we can use transaction rollback or we have to manually code to revert for these 2 functions `await RollbackBlobStorageAsync();` and `await RollbackDatabaseAsync();`

```
try 
{
  await Task.WhenAll(
    UpdateDatabaseAsync(),
    UpdateBlobStorageAsync(),
  );
} 
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
  await RollbackBlobStorageAsync();
}
catch (BlobStorageUpdateException)
{
  await RollbackDatabaseAsync();
}
```

===========

I am open to any suggestion.

- If they run one after the another, and we still have the ability to revert the first action, that's great too!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use transactions.
it is better to read the documentation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

Talking about your suggestion, keep in mind that database context is not [thread safe.](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18148)

```
var tasks = Task.WhenAll(
    UpdateDatabaseAsync(),
    UpdateBlobStorageAsync(),
  );

try{
    await tasks;
}
catch(exception ex){
    foreach (var inx in tasks.Exception.InnerExceptions)
    {
        log(inx);
    }
}

if(tasks.IsFaulted){
   await RollbackBlobStorageAsync();
   await RollbackDatabaseAsync();
}
```

Comment: Tks for responding, but I think it wouldn't work. I looked into Transaction/ Savepoints earlier, but there are 2 limitations 

1-it only deals with [update db via EF Core], it can't deal with [blob storage update] 

2-the rollback must be done within the same function, where as we don't have that luruxy (ef core dbcontext is in Repository file, whereas blobContainerClientWrapper is in another file)

Comment: Well I see. 
in that case you probably won't get these Exceptions since it might be another thread.  DbUpdateException, BlobStorageUpdateException.
You should do like that 
var task = Task.WhenAll()
try { await task} catch(exception)
if(task.IsFaulted) { await rollbackAsync(); await rollbackBlobAsync())